# Make absoluted positioned child wider than 100% but still automatic width

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, like this:

```
<div>
   <p>Parent</p>

   <div>
       <p>Child</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now, the child div content may be longer or shorter. If it's shorter, then the width is adapted correctly. However, if it's larger, the content wraps the line instead of spanning more than the 100% of the parent div.

I know I can set the width manually, but I'd like for the width to be automatic and be able to expand more than 100% (and have no white space left).

Comment: `white-space:nowrap` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```css
.child {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   Parent
   <div class="child">Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child Child </div>
</div>
```